# Elementary "binomial theorem" in English

Tags: terminology, binomial-theorem

In German schools, the identitiy $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ is called the *first binomial formula* (literally translated). However, it seems to me this English term only refers to the more general *binomial theorem* which involves the former as a special case, but is much more powerful and complex, or to formulas involving the binomial.

Is there special terminology taught in schools for this kind of formula? What would be the best way to describe the process of *creating a square* (similar to *completing the square*) as in $x^2 + 2x + 1 = (x+1)^2$?

Comment: Why is this here? It seems better asked on the Mathematics SE.

Comment: Well, it's not a maths, but a language usage question in my opinion, and since it's a topic taught in schools, I felt English SE was the place to get some insight. (I don't know if the amount of maths *teachers* is higer on Maths.SE), although I would not mind if this was moved to Maths.SE.

Comment: There might be a case to argue either way, but contextually, Mathematics.SE is answered in English and they will be the ones who would be able to suggest wording within their realm.

Comment: Well then, this seems reasonable. Can we get a moderator to move this?

Comment: I've flagged a mod request to migrate to Mathematics.SE, since I think this is domain-specific terminology, not directly relevant to ELU.

Comment: I usually call it the _quadratic formula_ in English.

Comment: that is certainly not the quadratic formula $x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} \over 2a}$ the solutions of $ax^2 + bx +c = 0$ which i know of. what we have here is an of the binomial theorem for positive exponents.

Comment: **Perfect square trinomial** is the name of the right-hand side. **Square of a binomial** is the left-hand side. **Perfect square trinomial formula**, or **square of a binomial formula**, are the names I have seen. The first more than any.

Comment: It seems that the German language wins in this case with "die erste binomische Formel". Although the names presented by @Pp.. are acceptable, I have not seen any standard name for such a formula.

Answer (score 1):

I might say of the folowing

- the simplest case of the binomial theorem.
- binomial theorem where the exponent is 2.
- binomial theorem where n = 2

Answer (score 1):

You want to start with $4x^2+4x+1$ and come up with $(2x+1)^2$ ... for that I might say $4x^2+4x+1$ *is a perfect square*.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience the usual school terminology treats it simply as a special case of *factor(is)ing*, alongside the distributive law, $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ and sometimes

$$a^3\pm b^3=(a\pm b)(a^2\mp ab+b^2)\;.$$

I’ve seen it called *square of a binomial*, but this name doesn’t seem to be as widespread as *difference of (two) squares* or even *difference/sum of (two) cubes*.